# Is there a dynamic checking utility that can flag overflow of static buffer in struct?

Tags: c, parasoft, purify

Is there a dynamic checking utility that can flag the following bug? Valgrind cannot. Can Purify or Insure++? This is on Linux Ubuntu latest version.

```
struct A {
    char buff1[8];
    int jj;
    char buff2[8];
    int ii;
    char buff3[8];
} a;

main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    // Set intermediate fields to known flag value
    a.ii = a.jj = 0xdeadbeef;

    // Write 8 char string into 8 byte buffer - null will overflow into neighboring int field. ERROR
    sprintf(a.buff2, "ABCDEFGH");
}
```

Comment: snprintf? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

Comment: This is an astute and helpful (and concise!) comment that does not answer my question, which I think says more about my question than the response! Your suggestion is the correct way to write the code. Unfortunately, I have 100,000 of legacy code, that now yields some 500 Klocwork issues, and would like to find out if any of this crap actually causes run-time errors. We're going to just grit our teeth and plunge into the refactoring.

Comment: In my experience Purify will do just what you want - along with checking stack variable usage..  When IBM owned it, you used to be able to get a 30-day demo license.  Also, one of the tools in Oracle's Studio compiler suite *may* also be able to find such a bug and it's free, although using the Oracle tools in my experience has a much greater performance impact than using Purify.  Also, my experience with the Oracle tools is on Solaris, which has much better instrumentation than Linux does.

Comment: @Andrew Henle I am pretty sure such a tool doesn't exist for reasons mentioned in my answer

Comment: @tofro Do you have actual experience using the tools I mentioned?  [Read this](http://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/purify/purify-4_1.pdf):  *In addition to detecting access errors in dynamic memory, Purify
detects references beyond the boundaries of data in global
variables and static variables, that is, data allocated statically at
link-time as opposed to dynamically at run time.*  I'll even post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I do. I have been working with Purify for years. My point is: There is *legal and unavoidable cases* for writing over structure bounds. Maybe I did not make myself clear enough.

Comment: @tofro *There is legal and unavoidable cases for writing over structure bounds.*  Ouch.  That would be some difficult code to debug, and yes, no tool could do it.  Still, given the OP's statement of `100,000 [lines] of legacy code` that need to be debugged, I'd opine that tools such as Purity are **required**.  You wouldn't ask a carpenter that only uses a 16-oz claw hammer and a 12" manual miter saw in lieu of modern power tools to build your house - the productivity cost would be prohibitive.  Yet developers at $100/hr or more are supposed to eschew tools like Purify over cost? Stupid.

Comment: @Andrew Henle You might want to read my answer below on why I say that. And I didn't talk about whether such tools are useful or not. They are. So the rest of your statement is just preaching to the converted... The OP did, however, ask a very specific question on what tools like Purify can and cannot do. And, to my knowledge, they can't.

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge. Most (or rather: all?) memory verification tools work in a way that embeds read- and write protected pages as guard zones *between* and around variables in order to provoke traps on accesses beyond the legally allocated areas.

Without severely disturbing structure alignment and integrity, this cannot be easily done *in the middle* of a structure.

EDIT:
Another point is: There is constructs where writing over structure member bounds is perfectly legal and the only reasonable possibility to achieve what you want. One example is copying structures to the heap:

```
struct x orig, *copy;

orig.a = 100;
strcpy (orig.str, "Test");

copy = malloc (sizeof (struct x));
memcpy (copy, &orig, sizeof (struct x));
```

This writes beyond structure member bounds as well, but is the only reasonable (and perfectly legal) way to get the structure onto the heap (apart from tedious and slow member-wise copy).

Another example would be

```
p = malloc (NUM_STRUCTS * sizeof (struct x));
memset (p, NUM_STRUCTS * sizeof (struct x), 0);
```

This is a perfectly valid constuct that allows you to clear an array of structures on the heap - And it does not even write aross *internal* struct boundaries, but also *between* structs.

In some sense, even *calloc()* would write beyond structure member bounds....

And, as a definite answer from the (admittedly older) Purify User Manual I happend to find in one of my desk drawers:

> Purify detects array bounds errors in arrays within C structures only when the access extends beyond the entire structure

That counts as a "no" for me.

Comment: I take your point about "disturbing structure alignment". Such a hypothetical tool would only be applied to code which is indifferent to alignment or size.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a **dynamic** tool?  The only tool I know which will detect the above scenario is Coverity, a **static** tool from Synopsis.  For the above case it will produce a report on the form of:

```
Error: OVERRUN:
...
sprintf_overrun: "sprintf" will overrun its first argument "a.buff2" which can accommodate 8 bytes.  The number of bytes written may be 9 bytes, including the terminating null.
```

Answer (score -1):

Compiling with all warnings enabled is a good start:

```
chqrlie@mac ~/dev/stackoverflow > clang -O3 -std=c11 -Weverything -lm -o 35996676 35996676.c
35996676.c:9:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main(int argc, char *args[])
^
35996676.c:12:19: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'unsigned int' to 'int' [-Wsign-conversi
    a.ii = a.jj = 0xdeadbeef;
                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~
35996676.c:15:5: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'sprintf' with type 'int (char *, const cha
    sprintf(a.buff2, "ABCDEFGH");
    ^
35996676.c:15:5: note: include the header <stdio.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'sprintf'
35996676.c:9:10: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
main(int argc, char *args[])
         ^
35996676.c:9:22: warning: unused parameter 'args' [-Wunused-parameter]
main(int argc, char *args[])
                     ^
35996676.c:7:3: warning: no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'a' [-Wmissing-variable-dec
} a;
  ^
6 warnings generated.
```

Fixing these with simple patches, and adding extra obvious bugs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static struct A {
    char buff1[8];
    unsigned int jj;
    char buff2[8];
    unsigned int ii;
    char buff3[8];
} a;

int main(void) {
    // Set intermediate fields to known flag value
    a.ii = a.jj = 0xdeadbeef;

    // Write 8 char string into 8 byte buffer - null will overflow into neighboring int field. ERROR
    sprintf(a.buff1, "ABCDEFGH");
    strcpy(a.buff2, "ABCDEFGH");
    sprintf(a.buff3, "%s", "ABCDEFGH");

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles with no warnings, is spite of the obvious `sprintf` and `strcpy` bugs that a simplistic static analysis should have caught.

`gcc` with `-Wall -W -Wextra` does not see anything wrong either.

It is recommended to use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, but that would not prevent the `strcpy` problem. `strcpy` is unsafe in the general case, but with a string literal as a source, the compiler should definitely complain.

You should try Frama-c, a powerful source code analysis framework available in open source from http://frama-c.com/

Comment: Thx. See my comment to user3528438 above.

Comment: A dynamic tool would indeed need to use some very advanced mechanism to detect such buffer overflows.  If you are able to recompile the whole project, specific padding of some of the structure members would be possible and would allow such detection.  Fat pointers or some other bound checking techniques could help too.  You can try `tinycc` with boundchecking enabled.  But static analysis and defensive programming will help locate a lot of problems.

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, Purify may do what you want.  This is an excerpt from an older [Purify user's manual posted to the internet](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs343/resources/purify-ug.pdf):

> **How Purify checks statically allocated memory**
>
> In addition to detecting access errors in dynamic memory, Purify
>   detects references beyond the boundaries of data in global variables
>   and static variables, that is, data allocated statically at link-time
>   as opposed to dynamically at run time.
>
> Here is an example of data that is handled by the static checking
>   feature:
>
> ```
> int array[10];
> main() {
>     array[11] = 1;
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, Purify reports an ABW error at the assignment to
>   `array[11]` because it is 4 bytes beyond the end of the array.

Comment: And that is *not* one of the cases the original question was asking for.

Comment: @tofro If Purify from almost 20 years ago can find problems accessing static variables like `int x[10];`, it should also be able to find problems accessing `struct A { int x[10]; ... } a;`.  They're both just locations in the same type of memory.

Comment: Note: I am *not* talking about static or dynamic variables and the OP wasn't as well. You should read my answer below on why I think a tool *shouldn't* flag such out-of bounds - because they are perfectly legit

Comment: Maybe that one helps (From the *Purify* manual): "Purify detects array bounds errors in arrays within C structures only when the access extends beyond the entire structure"